# WebSocket PHP works fine on Local but not when setup on a server for public

Tags: php, ubuntu, networking, websocket

I've setup a websocket server on local, and I'm able to make request on it. 127.0.0.1:2345,

But when setup the WebSocket on a AWS Ubuntu 18 server, I'm unable to make request at the 1.2.3.4:2345 (Assume that's my server IP).

What is the step that I might be missing?

Comment: you will need to make sure the in EC2 security group you've port 12345 allowed.

Comment: yes, that was the solution, indeed. I thought I had to do some NAT or something. But it was just that. Whitelisting port in the EC2 security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a matter of whitelisting the post `2345` in the security groups in AWS attached to the instance.

I thought I had to do some NAT or something. But it wasn't the case.

Whitelisting port in the EC2 security group. is the solution.